# Menu items showAsAction="never" are completely gone

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have this `menu.xml`:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>    
     <item
        android:id="@+id/action_connect"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_goto"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_connect"/>

     <item
        android:id="@+id/action_upgrade"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_refresh"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_upgrade"/>
</menu>
```

With this `Activity` code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

And only the `action_settings` action button appears. I would expect the other two to be available through the "three-dotted" menu, or the device's menu button. On the LG Optimus L3, the three-dotted menu does not appear and the device's menu button does nothing. On my Galaxy Nexus the menu does appear.

I want these other settings in a seperate menu because I don't want them to be tapped by accident. According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) (emphasis mine):

> The action bar provides users access to the **most important** action items relating to the app's current context.

If I cannot put it in the ActionBar menu, where to put the less-important action items?

Comment: Does the MENU button work on any app? If not, you have a broken MENU button on the device itself. Your overflow items should appear via the MENU button.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes, the button does work on other apps...

Answer (score 0):

It is because the LG has a hard menu button. When you press the menu button on the device, you should see the other two items.

Also, your placement of the settings icon is incorrect:

> Even if there's room in the action bar, never make Settings an action
>   button. Always keep it in the action overflow and label it "Settings".
>   Place it below all other items except "Help".

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/settings.html#flow-structure

Comment: As I said in my question, when I press the hardware button, the other options do not show.

Comment: Are you using the ActionBarActivity? It seems your xml isn't using the support namespaces, e.g., Add the namespace to the menu.xml file.

xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

2 - set the showAsAction to always or ifRoom

yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"

Comment: No, I am using a simple `Activity`, but I am targeting just one device (the LG optimus L3), so I do not have the support library installed. If I set them to `ifRoom`, they always show up, I don't want that. I want them in a "this-is-not-very-important" menu.

Comment: @BartFriederichs: Try dropping your `android:orderInCategory="100"` attributes. You do not need them, and they are the only thing that I can think of that is unusual about your setup.

Comment: @CommonsWare no effect

Comment: @BartFriederichs, http://www.phonearena.com/phones/LG-Optimus-L3_id6941 says that it is a 2.3 device.

Comment: @runor49 it's the LG Optimus L3-II (didn't even know there was a difference): http://www.gsmarena.com/lg_optimus_l3_ii_e430-5292.php